# Are these equivalent representations (labelled graph and adjacency matrix)?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, computer-science, spectral-graph-theory

This is an example from Wikipedia's [page on adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), which from the site's format seems to be suggesting equivalence between the simple diagram below, left, and the abstractly represented matrix on the right - I can't see how this is working though, as taking it as binary it doesn't read right and taking it as a coordinate map I don't understand how edges are being represented:

[image]

Kind of mystifying adjacency matrices for me right now, can anyone explain?

Comment: The entry $a_{ij}$ is $1$ if the vertex $j$ is connected with the vertex $i$. See the first column. $1$ is connected with $1$; also $2,5$ are connected with $1$.

Comment: ah yes I see! ingenious

Comment: @Sigur Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix simply represents the connection between the nodes.

The entry $a_{ij}$ is:

- $1$ if the node $j$ is connected with the node $i$;
- $0$ otherwise.

See the first column. Node $1$ is connected with $1$; also nodes $2,5$ are connected with $1$.